# What is the role of ControllerManagerConfig generated in kubebuilder

Tags: kubernetes, kubebuilder

I use `kubebuilder` to quickly develop `k8s operator`, and now I save the yaml deployed by `kustomize` to a file in the following way.

```
create: manifests kustomize ## Create chart
    cd config/manager && $(KUSTOMIZE) edit set image controller=${IMG}
    $(KUSTOMIZE) build config/default --output yamls
```

I found a configmap, but it is `not referenced by other resources`.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  controller_manager_config.yaml: |
    apiVersion: controller-runtime.sigs.k8s.io/v1alpha1
    kind: ControllerManagerConfig
    health:
      healthProbeBindAddress: :8081
    metrics:
      bindAddress: 127.0.0.1:8080
    webhook:
      port: 9443
    leaderElection:
      leaderElect: true
      resourceName: 31568e44.ys7.com
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myoperator-manager-config
  namespace: myoperator-system
```

I am a little curious what it does? can i delete it?

I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

It is another way to provide controller configuration. Check that https://book.kubebuilder.io/component-config-tutorial/custom-type.html .
However, it should be mounted in your deployment and the file path must be provided in the --config flag (the name of the flag can be different in your case, but "config" is used in the tutorial - it depends on your code)